# Percorrer array e localizar um caracter diferente de um numero

Tags: java, array

A ideia é receber um numero de 4 digitos e depois realizar uma variedade de contas mas existe uma condição de entrada:
Caso no meio dos 4 digitos esteja um caracter que não um numero então necessito de o imprimir.

Sem utilização de metodos.

Não consigo realizar o seguinte código:

Receber uma entrada exemplo: 3?56

- Guardar {3, ?, 5 ,6} num array sem saber qual é a entrada.
- Verificar se alguma das posições do array não está entre 0 e 9.

Neste caso ? não é um numero então imprime.

Eu queria guardar nas 4 posições do array.

```
    int i;
    char [] digitos = new char[3];
    digitos [0] = 
    digitos [1] = 
    digitos [2] = 
    digitos [3] = 
    for(i=0; i<digitos.length; i++);{
        if(digitos[i]<(char)0||digitos[i]>(char)9) System.out.println("Digito "+digitos[i]+" invalido");
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: O que você já tentou? Que linguagem está usando?

Comment: Linguagem Java.

Comment: Já está peço desculpa

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários problemas no trecho de código. Vamos lá:

1 - `char [] digitos = new char[3];`

Se você quer um array com 4 elementos, seu tamanho precisa ser quatro, seu índice máximo é 3, pois começa do índice 0.

2 - `for(i=0; i<digitos.length; i++);{`

Esse `;` faz com que o i extrapole o tamanho do vetor, dessa forma você deve removê-lo.

3 - `if(digitos[i]<(char)0||digitos[i]>(char)9) System.out.println("Digito "+digitos[i]+" invalido");
   System.exit(0);`

Aqui existem 2 problemas. O primeiro é que a condição de comparação dos caracteres está incorreta pois o casting não vai resultar numa verificação válida da natureza dígito do caractere. Aqui você deve comparar char com char, pois fazendo esse casting você está comparando o código ascii com o char. O segundo problema é que teu exit está fora do if, fazendo assim que o programa encerre logo após a primeira iteração.

Então, com base nos problemas apresentados, a solução final seria algo como:

```
int i;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String numero = scanner.nextLine();
    char [] digitos = numero.toCharArray();
    for(i=0; i<digitos.length; i++){
        if(digitos[i]<'0' || digitos[i]>'9') { 
            System.out.println("Digito "+digitos[i]+" invalido");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não posso utilizar metodos.
A questão é que como é que:
Guardo a entrada de maneira a separa-la em caracteres para depois serem introduzidos no array?

Comment: @BFR essa informação deveria estar na pergunta, por isso é importante adicionar o maximo de informações, senão acaba ocorrendo isso.

Comment: @diegofm Já corrigi. Vou estar mais atento a esse tipo de situações. Obrigado

Comment: Pronto, editei a resposta. Usa o scanner para ler e depois converter para o array de chars a string. Aí corrige a comparação dos chars sem utilizar métodos.

Comment: Muito obrigado.